# Is wood glue a good sealer to prevent water/moisture leakage?

Tags: water-protection, chipboard

***Context.*** I'm trying to design cheap interior doors, for areas including the bathroom.  Such doors will have hardwood frame and veneered plywood on the outside, but filled with chipboard.

***Goal.*** Make sure that water doesn't reach the chipboard.

***Question.*** Is wood glue adequate to achieve ***goal***?  If not, any recommendations for water-proofing chipboard?

Comment: You only need to concern yourself with exposure to liquid water, and in particular the exposed edges. Is it safe to assume you weren't planning on leaving these doors bare? If so the finish will do what you need.

Comment: *"Such doors will have hardwood as the structure only to hold the door in-shape, but filled with chipboard."* Do you mean frame-and-panel construction? And are you building these doors yourself??

Comment: @Graphus - Hardwood frame and veneered plywood on the outside.  To fill the void inside, I consider chipboard.  How does it matter if I'm doing it myself?  Do you know me and what resources I have?

Comment: I think Graphus asks because stated goal is cheap doors. This is confusing to me also because  doors as you describe already exist and they are cheapest available.

Comment: @VolframK - Yeah, they exist.  I didn't say the design is going to make new scientific breakthrough.

Comment: What do you mean by “chipboard”? In the US, that term often refers to a type of cardboard. I’m guessing you’re talking about particleboard, but other products like MDF and OSB are sometimes called “chipboard.”

Comment: Does this video help you? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y7HhE2p-8O0

Comment: @Caleb, chipboard = particleboard in UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is wood glue adequate to achieve goal?

There are different types of wood glue with varying degrees of water resistance. I suppose that if you coat the substrate with TiteBond III you’d add some water resistance. That said, if I wanted to seal a wood product and make it waterproof, glue wouldn’t be my first (or even fifth) choice. I’d use one of the many products intended for that. If you Google “waterproof wood sealer” you’ll find quite a few good options. And as Graphus already noted, the finish that you put on the door may be enough by itself.